# How do i interpret Johansen's test? (Matlab)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, matlab, cointegration

I found several similar questions with no answer. But I'm gonna give it a shot anyway.

I'm trying to find assets (stocks) which are co-integrated, since Engle-Granger's test may give cause to spurious regression it's suggested by several articles that you use Johansen's test as well to ensure a long-term co-integration. Even though I've not taken any course in time series analysis yet the Engle-Granger's test was not to difficult to understand. Johansen's test was on the other hand slightly more challenging, so I'm trying to understand how the interpret the results you're given in matlab.

So when I run the test for a nx2 vector in Matlab I get a 1x2 matrix as result with the inputs true or false. So the question is when I can reject/not reject the hypothesis.

```
************************
```

Results Summary (Test 1)

Data: 
Effective sample size: 13
Model: H1
Lags: 0
Statistic: trace
Significance level: 0.05

## r  h  stat      cValue   pValue   eigVal

0  1  23.6646   15.4948  0.0031   0.7486
1  1  5.7169    3.8415   0.0170   0.3558

h =

```
      r0       r1   
t1    true     true
```

pValue =

```
      r0           r1      
t1    0.0031234    0.016977
```

stat =

```
      r0        r1    
t1    23.665    5.7169
```

cValue =

```
      r0        r1    
t1    15.495    3.8415
```

mles =

```
      r0              r1          
t1    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample copy of your output?  Be sure to mark it up as 'code' using the curly brackets button.

Comment: I edited the post. But this is not the correct data though. I have all the data on excel-files stored on another computer. Now I'm just trying to understand how I should interpret the results. So I just created two vectors (14x1) and ran the cointegration for them. What's confusing is that it tests multiple hypothesises (?) and what can I then say if 1 says true and the other one false, etc.